# MiniZinc int out of range

Tags: solver, minizinc, gecode

I am trying to create a function in MiniZinc that can determine the distance between a line and a point. I want the function to only use integers. My idea is as follows:
In the case the point is not perpendicular to the line, the closest point should be chosen. If the point is perpendicular to the line, I want to approximate the point and then calculate the distance to the approximated point.

However when I am implementing this, I keep getting errors like below with Gecode and other solvers:

```
Error: The literal '-8004400200000' of the type int is out of range (-2147483646..2147483646) in line no. 13
Error: syntax error, unexpected FZ_DOTDOT in line no. 13
=====ERROR=====
```

Why does it say the int is out of range when they are nowhere near the maximum integer value?

My code:

````
var 0..100: u;
var 0..100: v;
var 0..100: w;
var 0..100: x;
var 0..100: y;
var 0..100: z;

var 0..20000: a = distancePointLine(u, v, w, x, y, z);

function var 0..20000: distancePointLine(var 0..100: x, var 0..100: y, var 0..100: x1, var 0..100: y1, var 0..100: x2, var 0..100: y2) =
  let {
  var -200..200: dot = (x-x1) * (x2-x1) + (y-y1) * (y2-y1);
  var -2000..2000: dot10 = ((x-x1) * (x2-x1) + (y-y1) * (y2-y1)) * 10;
  var -20000..20000: len = (x2-x1) * (x2-x1) + (y2-y1) * (y2-y1);
  var 0..2000: param = if len == 0 then -1 else dot div len endif;
  var 0..10: onLine = if param != 0 then 1 else dot10 div len endif;
  var 0..100: xLine = if param < 0 then x1 elseif param >= 1 then x2 else pointLine(x1,x2,onLine) endif;
  var 0..100: yLine = if param < 0 then y1 elseif param >= 1 then y2 else pointLine(y1,y2,onLine) endif;
  var 0..20000: distance = (x-xLine) * (x - xLine) + (y-yLine) * (y-yLine);
  } in distance;
  
function var 0..100: pointLine(var int: x1, var int: x2, var 0..10: segment) = 
  let {
    var 0..100: point = 10 * x1 + segment * (x1-x2) div 10;
  } in point;
  
solve maximize a;

output [
         "Res: \(a) ",
         ];
    ```
````

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that some calculated value (-8004400200000) is outside the possible supported domain of a variable (which is in the range -2147483646..2147483646 for Gecode). And the reason for that is the unlimited (and large) domains in `distancePointLine` were most variables are defined as `var int`, e.g. `dot`, `dot10`, `len`; and `distance` has a very large domain.

To fix the error for this specific problem, you can restrict the domain of the variable `a`, e.g.

```
var 0..10000: a = distancePointLine(7, 6, w, x, 100, 100);
```

Gecode then generate this solution:

```
Res: 8649 
----------
==========
```

However, some solvers (e.g. Chuffed) still has problem even with this: it throws  `Cannot handle non-sign-fixed vars`.

A better approach would be to restrict the domains of the variables in the function `distancePointLine`, if possible.

Comment: I followed your feedback and added bounds to all vars in my model (highest 20000). However it still comes up with the same error message. The code in the question is updated with your feedback.

Comment: @WouterMorssink That's strange. When I run your updated model it works with Gecode without any problem. What versions of MiniZInc and Gecode do you have? My versions are from MiniZincIDE (v2.5.5.): MiniZInc: v2.5.5 and Gecode: v6.3.1 .

Comment: I also have MiniZinc v2.5.5. For Gecode v6.3.0.

Comment: @WouterMorssink Perhaps it's an issue with that Gecode version. Would it be possible that you test with Gecode v6.3.1?

Comment: Where could I find version 6.3.1? On github it only has 6.3.0 and I cannot also not find it on their website.

Comment: @WouterMorssink Gecode is included in the MiniZincIDE package/bundle (as well as Chuffed). See  https://www.minizinc.org/software.html

Comment: My MiniZincIDE came with Gecode 6.3.0. Did you update it manually in the solver configurations?

Comment: Gecode v6.3.1. is included in  the current bundle: "64 bit Linux binary archive (Ubuntu 16 or later)" (files are dated per 2021-03-19) . I don't know about the other packages/bundles.

Comment: Sadly I have a windows machine, which only comes with 6.3.0. Will setup a VM tomorrow to check.